# How to get variable passed from input box to another page

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am trying to get a variable from hidden INPUT text box to another page. I created a search.asp page, when I search a Form from this page, clicked search button, then view.asp page will open with that specific Form ID. On View.asp page, I created a link to open a new page called view2.asp that keeps the same Form ID. But it didn't work. Can you please help? Thanks.

view.asp code

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Menus Search</title>

</head>
<body>

<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
th, td {
    padding: 3px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--#include file="openConn.asp" -->   

<%
SET objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET objRS1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET objRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET objRS3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If Request.Form("FormSource") = "SubmitForm" Then

    For j = 1 to Request.Form("txtCount")-1
        strReport   = Request.Form("Report[" & j &"]")

        strValue    = split(strReport,"$")
        sMenuID     = strValue(0)
        sCategoryID = strValue(1)
        sStatus     = strValue(2)

'response.write strReport  & "::" & sMenuID & "::"  & sCategoryID & "::"  & sStatus & "<br>"
'response.end       
        sFormID     = Request.Form("FormID")

        sSQL =  "INSERT INTO Report (FormID, MenuID, CategoryID, Status) VALUES " &_
                "('" & sFormID & "', '" & sMenuID & "', '" & sCategoryID & "', '" & sStatus & "');" 
            objConn.Execute(sSQL)
    Next
End If
%>

<form action="" method="post" id="newMenu" name="frmReport"  onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<p>
<%
'''' RR added today
nFormID= Request("FormID") ''Request.Form("SearchObj")
response.write "FormID: " & nFormID & "<br>"

sSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM Form WHERE Formid = " & nFormID
''response.write "SQL:::: " & sSQL2 & "<br>"

    objRS2.Open sSQL2, objConn
    'response.Write sSQL2
    Do Until objRS2.EOF
        sFormName = objRS2("Form_Name")
%>
<h2><%= objRS2("Form_Name") %></h2>
<p><a href="#" onclick="openview2.asp();"/>Click me</a></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="idFormName" name="FormID" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%= objRS2("FormID") %>"><br />
<%
    objRS2.MoveNext
    Loop
    objRS2.Close
%>

<p>
<table>
<thead bgcolor="#336666" style="color:#FFFFFF">
    <tr>

        <td>Trainer Name:</td>
        <td>Pass</td>
        <td>Fail</td>
        <td>NA</td>
        <td>Not taken</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<%
currMenu = ""
sSQL =  "SELECT MenuID, Menu_Name FROM Menu where MENUID in (SELECT MENUID FROM Category where formid=" & nFormID & ")"

    objRS.Open sSQL, objConn
    i=1
    While Not objRS.EOF
        nMenuID     = objRS("MenuID")
        sMenuName   = objRS("Menu_Name")
        If currMenu <> sMenuName Then
            currMenu = sMenuName
            %>
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><%= sMenuName %></th>
            </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="MenuID" value="<%=nMenuID%>">
        <% 
        End If 
        sSQL3 = "SELECT Categoryid, Category_Name FROM Category WHERE MenuID = " & nMenuID & " and FormID=" &  nFormID
            Set objRS3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            objRS3.Open sSQL3, objConn
            While Not objRS3.EOF
                nCategoryID     = objRS3("Categoryid")
                sCategoryName   = objRS3("Category_Name")
        %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= sCategoryName %></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="CategoryID" value="<%=nCategoryID%>">
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$1"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$2"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$3"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$4"></td>
            </tr>
            <%
            objRS3.MoveNext
            i = i + 1
            Wend
            objRS3.Close
        objRS.MoveNext
    Wend
    objRS.Close
%>
</table>
</p>

<p>
<input type="hidden" name="txtCount" value="<%= i %>">
<input type="button" value="Create Menu" onclick="openwin();" />
<input type="hidden" name="FormSource" value="SubmitForm">
<input type="button" value="View2" onclick="openview2();" />
<input type="submit" value="Update">
<a href="search.asp">Go To Search</a>
</p>
</form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(daForm) {
nCount = document.frmReport.txtCount.value;

    // check all rb radio buttons
    for (var i = 1; i < nCount; i++) {
        if (! getCheckedRadioValue(daForm["Report"+i])) {
            alert ("Please select a value for option " + i)
            return false
        }
    }
    // add other checks here...
    return true
}
function getCheckedRadioValue(radio) {
    for (var i=0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) return radio[i].value
    }
    return false
}
function openwin()
{
    //alert($('#idFormName').val());
    //window.location.href = "Create.asp?FormID=" + $('#idFormName').val();

    window.open("Create.asp?FormID=" + $('#idFormName').val(), "Create New Menu", "menubar=0,width=700,height=450");

}
function openView2()
{
alert($('#idFormName').val());
    window.open("view2.asp?FormID=" + $('#idFormName').val(), "Create New Menu", "menubar=0,width=700,height=450");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

view2.asp

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Menus Search</title>

</head>
<body>

<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
th, td {
    padding: 3px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--#include file="openConn.asp" -->   

<%
SET objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET objRS1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET objRS2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SET objRS3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If Request("FormID")="" then
    iFormID =0
Else
    iFormID = Request("FormID") ''Request.Form("FormID")
End If

If Request.Form("FormSource") = "SubmitForm" Then

    For j = 1 to Request.Form("txtCount")-1
        strReport   = Request.Form("Report[" & j &"]")

        strValue    = split(strReport,"$")
        sMenuID     = strValue(0)
        sCategoryID = strValue(1)
        sStatus     = strValue(2)

'response.write strReport  & "::" & sMenuID & "::"  & sCategoryID & "::"  & sStatus & "<br>"
'response.end       
        sFormID     = Request.Form("FormID")

        sSQL =  "INSERT INTO Report (FormID, MenuID, CategoryID, Status) VALUES " &_
                "('" & sFormID & "', '" & sMenuID & "', '" & sCategoryID & "', '" & sStatus & "');" 
            objConn.Execute(sSQL)
    Next
End If
%>

<form action="" method="post" id="newMenu" name="frmReport"  onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<p>
<%
'''' RR added today
nFormID= Request("FormID") ''Request.Form("SearchObj")
response.write "FormID: " & nFormID & "<br>"

sSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM Form WHERE Formid = " & nFormID
''response.write "SQL:::: " & sSQL2 & "<br>"

    objRS2.Open sSQL2, objConn
    'response.Write sSQL2
    Do Until objRS2.EOF
        sFormName = objRS2("Form_Name")
%>
<h2><%= objRS2("Form_Name") %></h2>
    <input type="hidden" id="idFormName" name="FormID" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%= objRS2("FormID") %>"><br />
<%
    objRS2.MoveNext
    Loop
    objRS2.Close
%>

<p>
<table>
<thead bgcolor="#336666" style="color:#FFFFFF">
    <tr>

        <td>Trainer Name:</td>
        <td>Pass</td>
        <td>Fail</td>
        <td>NA</td>
        <td>Not taken</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<%
currMenu = ""
sSQL =  "SELECT MenuID, Menu_Name FROM Menu where MENUID in (SELECT MENUID FROM Category where formid=" & nFormID & ")"

    objRS.Open sSQL, objConn
    i=1
    While Not objRS.EOF
        nMenuID     = objRS("MenuID")
        sMenuName   = objRS("Menu_Name")
        If currMenu <> sMenuName Then
            currMenu = sMenuName
            %>
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><%= sMenuName %></th>
            </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="MenuID" value="<%=nMenuID%>">
        <% 
        End If 
        sSQL3 = "SELECT Categoryid, Category_Name FROM Category WHERE MenuID = " & nMenuID & " and FormID=" &  nFormID
            Set objRS3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            objRS3.Open sSQL3, objConn
            While Not objRS3.EOF
                nCategoryID     = objRS3("Categoryid")
                sCategoryName   = objRS3("Category_Name")
        %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= sCategoryName %></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="CategoryID" value="<%=nCategoryID%>">
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$1"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$2"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$3"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="radio" id ="Report<%=i%>"  name="Report[<%=i%>]" value="<%=nMenuID%>$<%=nCategoryID%>$4"></td>
            </tr>
            <%
            objRS3.MoveNext
            i = i + 1
            Wend
            objRS3.Close
        objRS.MoveNext
    Wend
    objRS.Close
%>
</table>
</p>

<p>
<input type="hidden" name="txtCount" value="<%= i %>">
<input type="button" value="Create Menu" onclick="openwin();" />
<input type="hidden" name="FormSource" value="SubmitForm">

<input type="submit" value="Update">
<a href="search.asp">Go To Search</a>
</p>
</form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(daForm) {
nCount = document.frmReport.txtCount.value;

    // check all rb radio buttons
    for (var i = 1; i < nCount; i++) {
        if (! getCheckedRadioValue(daForm["Report"+i])) {
            alert ("Please select a value for option " + i)
            return false
        }
    }
    // add other checks here...
    return true
}
function getCheckedRadioValue(radio) {
    for (var i=0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) return radio[i].value
    }
    return false
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a great question, you need to provide a [mcve] which this is not. Have you debugged the problem yourself? Use the Browser dev tools to identify what the value of `$('#idFormName').val()` is? As you're just passing the value to `view2.asp` as a `GET` request, have you tried opening `view2.asp` manually with the required querystring values filled in to observe the resulting page? These types of things should be attempted before even coming to [so] and asking a question.

Comment: I just added extra info to my solution since I found even more strange things in the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: @sumpen no, it doesn't help. They need to provide a [mcve] not just wait for someone gullable enough to do their debugging for them.

Comment: Yes. I added this line, alert($('#idFormName').val()); I got a value form FormID popup, but when I click on OK button, then view2.asp page shows 500 error. I also tried to open view2.asp on the browser with direct FormId as view2.asp?formID=2, it doesn't work either. view.asp is not a direct page, but is passed from search.asp for any Form ID. Thanks.

Comment: What is the 500 error, do you have errors enabled in IIS so you can get some feedback on the specific error, cause, line numbers etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to do.

But as I could understand, you want to open view2.asp and be able to have a value from view.asp there.

As I can see you open view2.asp with this line

```
<input type="button" value="View2" onclick="openview2();" />
```

And you want this hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="idFormName" name="FormID" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%= objRS2('FormID') %>">
```

If this is what you are trying to do. Then your naming is wrong with the javascript. You probably copied and forgot to change name.

See here, where you try to open ***view2.asp***

```
function openwin()
{
    window.openView2("view2.asp?FormID=" + $('#idFormName').val(), "Create New Menu", "menubar=0,width=700,height=450");
}
```

You need to change ***openwin()*** to ***openview2()***

EDIT:

I just also saw you have this strange code

```
<a href="#" onclick="openview2.asp();"/>Click me</a>
```

Which is a link to it self, because you have ***href="#"***. But you also trying to call a javascript function with this ***onclick="openview2.asp();"***.

You do not have a function called ***openview2.asp()***. And this is not how it works. 
If you are trying to call ***view2.asp*** with this link and pass the hidden input ***idFormName***. Then it's better if you just do a correct link and pass the ID in the url.
I must say it's a very bad solution, because there is no security here. But the code you provided shows that you are only after a function and ignoring any security aspect.

So change this

```
<h2><%= objRS2("Form_Name") %></h2>
<p><a href="#" onclick="openview2.asp();"/>Click me</a></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="idFormName" name="FormID" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%= objRS2("FormID") %>"><br />
```

for this

```
<h2><%= objRS2("Form_Name") %></h2>
<p><a href="view2.asp?idFormName=<%= objRS2("FormID") %>" />Click me</a></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="idFormName" name="FormID" value="<%= objRS2("FormID") %>"><br />
```

I'm leaving the hidden there in case you refer to this somewhere else in your code.

Good luck and Have a nice day!

Comment: Hello, I have to use href="#" to keep view.asp unchanged after I click to go to view2.asp. I added Openview2 function and added this line: alert($('#idFormName').val()); . I click on Click me to open view2.asp page, it pops up the right FormID, but when I click on OK to go to the page, then it shows 500 internal server error. The value FormID didn't get passed to the form. Thanks.

Comment: That is not how things work. Href="#" means scroll to top of page. It will not keep view.asp unchanged. If you are trying to go back to view.asp after being on view2.asp, then you need to to do same query for view.asp again.

Comment: view.asp is not a direct page, but is passed from search.asp for any Form ID. If I use this, <a href="view2.asp?idFormName=<%= objRS2("FormID") %>" />Click me</a>, then view.asp will error out by 500 error because it doesn't have any FormID after I open view2.asp

Comment: @JennyTran did you even listen to what I said yesterday or did you just choose to ignore it?

Comment: I replied to your comment above. Thanks.

Comment: I tried sumpen way again, and it worked perfect this time. Thanks very much.